# Android WebRTC with PeerConnection

Tags: java, android, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I need to create an app for android with Java for voice call, the data which are provided to me are: iceServer: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"], channelName and EventName. Are they enough to build an application for voice calls or even needed something for signaling? Thank you!!

Comment: I can help you, but there isn't enough space to explain

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need of course a Signalling server, you can find many good free open source servers in the Codelab, but if you really want to go for production I recommend hiring a backend developer who has experience with webrtc.
I also recommend to check for Socket.io to firing and catching events.

There is another option for Signaling, which is renting, take this for example:

https://www.ably.io/

https://www.simplewebrtc.com/

but you will pay for these

By the way webrtc in Android is a nightmare because of the lake of resources, so good luck.

Comment: @Mohammed, thanks for your response, is there any resource for implementing android client with any free open source server

Comment: https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk

Comment: https://github.com/EnableX/One-to-One-Video-Call-Webrtc-Application-Sample-for-Android

Comment: These are for Android side